# Java NullPointerException in if statement

Tags: java

I currently get the NullPointerException in my following code.

```
else if (isEmpty(href))
    System.err.println("This is an empty link: " + href);
```

Where the isEmpty function is the following.

```
public boolean isEmpty(String HREF){
    if (HREF.equals("") || HREF.equals("null") || HREF == null || HREF.isEmpty())  
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Is it because I can not compare a string to null? What can I do to make this function work?

Comment: try HREF=="null" and also it should be the first condition being checked

Comment: Look up `java boolean operator short circuit`, and then see why we recommend that the null check be done first. Note that @digidude is incorrect -- you do not surround null with quotes. It's `if (HREF == null || ...)`

Comment: Also when you do the comparison HREF.equals("null") , you are comparing HREF to a string "null", which could result in incorrect output when HREF="null"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `isEmpty` test is just doing things in the wrong order. Change this:

```
if (HREF.equals("") || HREF.equals("null") || HREF == null || HREF.isEmpty())  
    return true;
```

to:

```
if (HREF == null || HREF.equals("") || HREF.equals("null") || HREF.isEmpty())  
    return true;
```

If `HREF` is actually `null`, then the first test will [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) the rest of the `if` and you won't get a NPE.

(By the way, explicitly testing `HREF.equals("")` and also calling `HREF.isEmpty()` is redundant. You only need to do one or the other.)

By the by-the-way, I would recommend, as a matter of style simplifying your method to a single `return` statement:

```
public boolean isEmpty(String HREF){
    return HREF == null || HREF.isEmpty()) || HREF.equals("null");
}
```

(Also, if testing against the string `"null"` was an attempt to check against a `null` value, you can drop that condition as well. In fact, you could then use something like Apache Commons' [`StringUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) method to do what you want.)

Comment: If he just changes the order in `HREF.equals("")` then there will be no need to check for `HREF == null || HREF.isEmpty()`

Comment: @Ted .... keeping the check HREF.equals("null") could result in incorrect behavior when HREF="null" as he is doing a string comparison there.

Comment: @DanilGaponov - I agree about the `HREF.isEmpty()`, but `"".equals(HREF)` will be `false` if `HREF` is `null`, so an explicit null test would still be needed.

Comment: @digidude - I assumed that OP actually wants to treat the string `"null"` as "empty". Without knowing the broader logic of the program, I saw no need to change OP's semantics of the method.

Comment: @TedHopp ... Yeah. I just assumed otherwise. Let's leave it for him to decide   .... I thought I would just put it out there.   :)

Answer (score 1):

changing the order in your if will solve it.

```
public boolean isEmpty(String HREF) {
    return HREF == null || HREF.equals("") || HREF.equals("null") ||  HREF.isEmpty();
}
```

this way, when HREF == null, none of the other tests will be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

When HREF is null , referencing it with dot operator will throw a null pointer exception .

Different ways to solve this is as follows

```
  public boolean isEmpty(String HREF){
      if (HREF == null ||HREF.equals("") || HREF.equals("null") ||    HREF.isEmpty())  
          return true;
      else 
          return false;
 }
```

this is by just re arranging your conditions, by short cut of boolean operations, this will avoid referencing a null pointer in subsequent checks.

OR

```
  public boolean isEmpty(String HREF){
      //handling null case first of all
      if(HREF == null)   return true;

      if(HREF.equals("") || HREF.equals("null") ||    HREF.isEmpty())  
          return true;
      else 
          return false;
 }
```

Also avoid redundant use of checks like HREF.equals("") and HREF.isEmpty() are similar.

Another best practice to check equals with a string object is to use the constant in the beginning  as in   `"".equals(HREF)` and `"null".equals(HREF)`, here we are pretty sure that  `"null"` is a valid string and which is not  `null`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call methods of the null here `HREF.equals("")`
Common practice is to change the order `"".equals(HREF)` . This is null safe. And you will not need `HREF.isEmpty()` part this way.
So the code will become

```
public boolean isEmpty(String HREF){
     return HREF == null || "".equals(HREF) || "null".equals(HREF);
}
```

I have removed the unnecessary `if` here as we are returning the result of boolean expression.

Answer (score -1):

If `HREF` is null, then doing this:

```
HREF.equals("")
```

will throw a NPE.

Do the null check first:

```
HREF != null && /* rest of conditions */
```

Comment: @engineercoding: we all know that, I am just trying to have the answer itself be more complete so I can up-vote it.